# How to run a script at startup and access it later

Tags: boot, screen, startup, tmux, nohup

I want to run a script at startup that I will need to interact with later.  I could find ways to run a script at startup, but no ways to come back to it after it has run.  The script never ends.  I need to be able to enter things into the script.  I know nohup would work for starting it but I could not find a way to resume the script and interact with it.  I know tmux and screen will work for interacting with it, but I do not know how to run these commands in a single line to run them at startup.

TLDR: I need a way to run a never ending script at startup and resume this script later on.

Edit: It is for a minecraft server.  As far as interaction, I would need to be able to type commands and see the output.  All of this is through the command line.  This is very similar to an ssh session.  Very much like tmux and screen, I want to be able to resume a session at any time.

Comment: Could you explain what it should do, and what the interaction should be  exactly?